# How do I switch from syslog to rsyslog?

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

We are moving from a RHEL5.x platform to a RHEL6 platform. RHEL5.x had the syslogd while RHEL6.x has rsyslogd.

I have legacy C code that makes these kinds of calls

```
foo.c
#include <syslog.h>
...snip
syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Using configuration: %d\n", g_config_index+1);
...snip
```

How do I convert this to use rsyslog instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change anything. The `<syslog.h>` interface is not specific to syslogd; it's implemented by all system logger daemons, including rsyslogd as well as more exotic loggers like systemd.